# How do I `center' the text within 1 in margins?

Tags: spacing, margins

I need a document which is centered within 1in margins. As it stands, the document prints aligned to the left. Here is the code I use:

```
\documentclass[a4 paper,11pt]{article}
%\usepackage[inner=2.5cm,outer=2.5cm, bottom=2.5cm,showframe]{geometry}
\usepackage[margin=1in,includeheadfoot,showframe]{geometry}
%\usepackage[a4paper,margin=1in,showframe]{geometry}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage[round]{natbib}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
\usepackage{linguex}
\usepackage[doublespacing]{setspace}
\usepackage{graphicx} 
\usepackage{tikz-qtree}
\usepackage{tikz-qtree-compat}
\usetikzlibrary{fit}
\usepackage{soul}
\usepackage{linguex}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{tikz}
\newcommand*\circled[1]{\tikz[baseline=(char.base)]{
            \node[shape=circle,draw,inner sep=2pt] (char) {#1};}}
            \newcommand\encircle[1]{%
  \tikz[baseline=(X.base)] 
    \node (X) [draw,dashed, shape=circle, inner sep=0] {\strut #1};}
\usepackage{ulem}
\usepackage{pifont}% http://ctan.org/pkg/pifont
\newcommand{\cmark}{\ding{51}}%
\newcommand{\xmark}{\ding{55}}%
\usepackage{multicol}


\textwidth=15cm \hoffset=-1.2cm %
\textheight=25cm \voffset=-2cm %

\pagestyle{empty} %

\date{} %

\def\keywords#1{\begin{center}{\bf Keywords}\\{#1}\end{center}} %



% Please, do not change any of the above lines


\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhf{}
\rhead{Proposed Plan for Completing the Dissertation}
\lhead{}
\rfoot{\thepage}



\begin{document}
\end{document}
```

Thank you!

Here is the image of the printed text:

[image: printed document]

Comment: you can use `\centering` after `\begin{document}` but doe you _really_ want the whole document centred?  Also note that `\bf` should not be used (and isn't defined by default) in latex.

Comment: also it is rather inconsistent to set up teh page style with `geometry` and then undo its definitions with low level assignments `\textwidth=15cm \hoffset=-1.2cm %
\textheight=25cm \voffset=-2cm %`

Comment: you don't show any code that would cause left alignment, I would expect teh default justified text flush to both left and right margin.

Comment: When print the document, it looks as if the entire text is slightly moved to the left given the entire space. Maybe I am not explaining well, I'd like to show the printed pdf, but I am not sure how to post it here.

Comment: your example has no text so it isn't an example of any alignment at all, you can take a screenshot of the pdf view and upload it using the editor

Comment: you have arbitrarily shifted the text block to the right by  \hoffset=-1.2cm  so the text block will not be centred on the page.

Comment: You want ISO A4 paper, which is 21cm wide. If you want 1in margin, then the text width will be 21 − 5.08 = 15.92cm and it's nonsense to set `\textwidth=15cm`. ***Never*** monkey with `\hoffset` and `\voffset`. Leave the job to `geometry`.

Comment: please also trim your preamble for future questions you should post a _minimal_ example, your current preamble loads multiple unused packages, some of them more than once.

Comment: I just added the screenshot. It looks like there is more 'space' to the right of the text of the body than to the left, so it doesn't look as if the margin is 1in on all sides, as a word document with identical margin settings would look like. thanks!!

Comment: of course there is not a 1in margin as, as I comment above, you completely over-write the `geometry` settings, what is the intention of `\textwidth=15cm \hoffset=-1.2cm %
\textheight=25cm \voffset=-2cm %`  you should delete those lines if you want the margin that you specified to `geometry`.